# In what format Karate is backing up the Default Junit Html Report in target folder when Runner API is used? Is it TimeStamp or some other value?

Tags: karate

Parallel Runner

```
@Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:com/tests/QueryAndPathParameter.feature")
                .parallel(4);
                assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
```

Target folder screenshot

[image]

Is the value after karate-reports_ is timestamp or some other value. From where that value is coming?

Comment: Got it 170615807124 is a unix time stamp. Converted using this website https://www.timestamp-converter.com/ and got the time according to time zone.

Comment: yes, you can disable this if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66685944/143475