# Karate API framework- test dependency

Tags: api, karate

In my regression suite I have 600+ test cases. All those tests have @RegressionTest tag. See below, how I am running.

```
  _start = LocalDateTime.now();
    //see karate-config.js files for env options
    _logger.info("karate.env = " + System.getProperty("karate.env"));

    System.setProperty("karate.env", "test");
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:functional/Commercial/").tags("@RegressionTest").reportDir(reportDir).parallel(5);
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
```

I am thinking that, I can create 1 test and give it a tag @smokeTest. I want to be able to run that test 1st and only if that test passes then run the entire Regression suite. How can I achieve this functionality? I am using Junit5 and Karate.runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is run one test in JUnit itself, and if that fails, throw an Exception or skip running the actual tests.

So use the `Runner` two times.

Otherwise consider this not supported directly in Karate but code-contributions are welcome.

Also refer to the answers to this question: [How to rerun failed features in karate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53912893/143475)