# Unable to switch between environment in karate feature file

Tags: karate

As per KARATE documentatoion we should use System.setProperty() to set env in test case level, But that option is not working in karate 1.2.0 (Didn't verify in previous versions)

Feature

```
Feature: Testing env changing
  Scenario: Reading base url of different env
  * print 'Before changing env...---> '+ karate.env
  * print 'Testing karate...'
  * print baseUrl
  * java.lang.System.setProperty("karate.env","STAGE")
  * def newevn = java.lang.System.getProperty('karate.env')
  * print 'After changing env...---> '+ newevn
  * def fun = call read('file:karate-config.js') 
  * print 'Changed env...---> '+ fun.baseUrl
```

Karate-Config.js file-

```
function fn() {
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  var env = karate.env;
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);

  var baseUrl = 'testingbase.com';
  karate.log('Env---->' + env)
  var port = karate.properties['demo.server.port'] || '8080';
  var protocol = 'http';

  var config = {
    env: env,
    baseUrl: 'https://localapi.abc123.example.com/api/v1/validate/customerid',
    apiKey: ''
  }
  if (karate.properties['demo.server.https'] === 'true') {
    protocol = 'https';
    karate.configure('ssl', true);
  }
  var config = { demoBaseUrl: protocol + '://127.0.0.1:' + port };
  if (env== 'mock') {
    // karate.configure('callSingleCache', { minutes: 1 });
    // 'callSingle' is guaranteed to run only once even across all threads
    //var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:demo/headers/common-noheaders.feature', config);
    // and it sets a variable called 'authInfo' used in headers-single.feature
   // config.authInfo = { authTime: result.time, authToken: result.token };
  }
  else if(env=='BETA'){
 config.baseUrl='tetsing.beta.base.com';

  }
  else if(env=='STAGE'){
config.baseUrl='tetsing.stage.base.com';

  }
  return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you can't call `java.lang.System.setProperty()` within a feature and expect that to work. The environment is locked in at the time that `karate-config.js` is evaluated, which is before a `Feature` even executes.

Please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#switching-the-environment

Comment: Is there any way to switch between env and hit request, Just to verify response between different environment.

Comment: @ShridharaMJ just use the `Runner` API twice ? see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72253684/143475 - otherwise maybe you over-engineered your tests and what you need is not 2 environments but a single test with 2 data-driven rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092767/143475